# Why does this React component return 9 errors

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm working on building an app for a react codecademy course I wrote this reat component and it returns 9 errors and I do not understand why.
I get errors such as "declaration or statement expected", "; expected" or "argument expected"

```
import React from "react";
import "searchbar.css";

export class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div class="className">
                <input placeholder="Enter A Song, Album, or Artist">
                <button class="className">SEARCH</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should close input tag

```
<input placeholder="Enter A Song, Album, or Artist" />
```